# Node JS - How does one stub a soap function call for unit testing

Tags: node.js, mocking, soap-client

How can I effectively mock out responses to remote system calls while writing unit tests. The method in question is this one:

```
client.SomeFunction(input, function(err, result)) {...}
```

The code that contains it is here:

```
'use strict';
var soap               = require('soap');
var responseBuilder    = require('./responseBuilder');
var errorHandler       = require('../src/errorHandler');

/**
 * Execute the soap client
 */
exports.executeSoapClient = function (input, headers, wsdlOptions, wsdlPath) {

    var soapClientPromise = new Promise( function( resolve, reject){

        var response = responseBuilder.buildResponse();

        //Call SOAP Client
        soap.createClient(wsdlPath, wsdlOptions, function (err, client) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err, err.stack);
                reject( errorHandler.createError("Unexpected: Could not communication with remote system.", 500) );
            }

            client.addSoapHeader(headers, "", "tkn", "http://siebel.com/webservices");
            //This is the function I want to mock out.
            client.SomeFunction(input, function (err, result) {

                if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    reject( errorHandler.createError("Unexpected: Unexpected: Could not call remote function on remote system.", 500) );
                } else {
                    if (result.Error_spcCode > 0) {
                        var errorMessage = result.Error_spcMessage + " (" + result.Error_spcCode + ")";
                        var error = errorHandler.createError("Business rule violation in remote system: " + errorMessage, 401);
                        console.error(error);
                        reject( error );
                    } else {
                        var successMessage = { flexId: result.FLEXId , message: result.Message };
                        resolve( response.success( successMessage ) );
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    return soapClientPromise;
};
```

This code is eventually going to be run as an AWS Lambda, which is why the function needs to be named in that fashion.

Answer (score -2):

you can use sinon.js to stub your function that call soap.

good tutorial >> https://semaphoreci.com/community/tutorials/best-practices-for-spies-stubs-and-mocks-in-sinon-js